# Do some items make the Blood Moon event more common?

Tags: terraria

I'm playing in a new 1.2 world, and the Blood Moon rises nearly every night! My character is currently weak enough that I'm having a tough time staying alive, and it's getting to be frustrating. Are there items in the game world that make the Blood Moon event more likely to happen? Or is lady luck just giving me the finger?

I'm specifically wondering about some of the new monster banners that you can obtain. I've put a few of the ones I've obtained up in my character's castle; could one of these be the source of the never-ending Blood Moons?

Comment: it's probably lady luck, I have three banners hanging and haven't had a single blood moon yet.

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible. Maybe in future updates it will be. But you can increase the enemy spawn rate using a Water Candle.

Comment: Sometimes, many Bloodmoons can happen in a row, and it can suck for new players who are just getting their gear organized.  I would suggest, to help survive this unfortunate circumstance, to start barricading your entryway with blocks to protect from zombies, and spending more time underground, where the effects are less noticeable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are **no items** that make the Blood Moon more common.  The monster banners are actually just decoration.  The only items that affect the Blood Moon are the ones that make monster spawn rate higher, and if there is an item, you probably don't have it, since your character is currently weak.

Answer (score 2):

The **Bloody Tear** (added in 1.4) can be used to instantly start a Blood Moon.

Other than that, there is nothing that changes the likelihood of a Blood Moon. It's just random luck.

Answer (score -6):

There is one item that makes you have a Blood Moon, and they are Topazes.